# Probability that the p-value is less than 0.05 if H0 is true?

Tags: self-study, p-value, likelihood-ratio

Suppose that under $H_0$, a measurement $X$ is $N(0,\sigma^2 )$, and that under $H_1$, $X$
is $N(1,\sigma^2 )$ and that the prior probability $P(H_0) = P(H_1)$.

With $\sigma$ = 1, what is the probability that the p-value is
less than 0.05 if $H_0$ is true? What is the probability if $H_1$ is true?

Here are my calclations:

Because we have the prior probability $P(H_0) = P(H_1)$,than our likelihood ratio will be:$$\frac{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\dfrac{-x^2}{2}}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\dfrac{-(x-1)^2}{2}}$$

terms with $\pi$ canceled out and we got the following inequality:
$$\frac{e^\dfrac{-x^2}{2}}{e^\dfrac{-(x-1)^2}{2}} >1$$

Solving for x we got:

$$\frac{1-2x}{2} >ln(1)  => x<1/2$$

Are my calculations and the way of solving the problem right?
If yes, what should i do next? Because i don't understand how can i find the probability that the p-value is
less than 0.05

Comment: This is a strange post.  Why are you involving a prior probability distribution in your calculations when the two parts of the question stipulate that $H_0$ is true or $H_1$ is true?  It makes one suspect that you haven't successfully communicated the problem you wish to solve.

Comment: There is a *lot* of detail missing from this post. Frequentists can speak of a probability that $p$ is less than 0.05 because it is calculated from a hypothetical distribution of a test statistic. $p$ is not a parameter. It looks like you're basing your test on the likelihood ratio statistic (in your first display). You can do a MUCH better job reducing the equation. Take its log, it *will* be a known distribution.

Comment: @whuber can you give me a hint how to solve this problem correctly?

Comment: Do it in three steps.  First decide what test statistic you will use.  (Your question doesn't say anything about this.)  Then you can find the critical region for the test. Finally, for each hypothesis, compute the chance that the test statistic lies in the critical region.

Comment: @whuber i think, that in this case i should use likelihood-ratio test and from this test we got, that `exp[(1-x^2)/2] <c` ,where c is some constant.

Then we ca find the value `c` from this equation - this will be our critical region.
Am i right?

Comment: For a continuous statistic and a point null, it really doesn't matter what the statistic is, we can calculate the probability that the p-value is less than 0.05 under the null by elementary arguments.

Comment: @Glen_b as whuber said, i chose L-R statistic and found critical region(we will reject H0 for x<0.5). 

But how can we find, the probability? that p-value is less that 0.05 under the null ? My calculation was P(x<0.5 |Ho) = 0.30. But that is an alpha.

Comment: Your rejection rule doesn't matter here, we're discussing p-values. Let's assume you can correctly (exactly) calculate your p-values. What is the distribution of the p-value if the null is true?

Comment: @Glen_b standard normal distribution.

Comment: P-values are necessarily between 0 and 1. How would they have a standard normal distribution?

Comment: @Glen_b of course the p-value distribution is uniform.
I am sorry for the first answer:)

Comment: If a p-value is U(0,1), what is the probability that it is less than 0.05?

Comment: @Glen_b 0.05...omg that is so easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We know in frequentist testing that the likelihood ratio test is UMP, and because it is a monotone, continuous likelihood ratio statistic, the test *should* be of the right size. Asymptotic theory tells us that 2 times the *log* likelihood ratio has an asymptotic $\chi^2_1$ distribution. A good "hunch" might be to realize that normal random variables should be ideal sailing conditions and this would be a finite sample property.

You've presented the likelihood ratio statistic in the first display. But reduce it using exponent rules and take it's log. Formally describe which test you will apply.